# How to grab data from selected row in React MUI Data-Grid table with Axios

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, datagrid, state

I am trying to use the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/66424752get-row-item-on-checkbox-selection-in-react-material-ui-data-grid-wp4vl?file=/demo.tsx) to add the `selectedRow` functionality from @mui/x-data-grid to return all the data form a selected row. In the demo, they are using the `useDemoData` mod to populate the table, whereas I am using `Axios` to make a call to my API to populate the rows and using preconfigured columns.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import { DataGrid, GridToolbar } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'Job ID', width: 170 },
    { field: 'file_name', headerName: 'File Name', width: 250 },
    { field: 'product_type', headerName: 'Product Type', width: 300 },    
    { field: 'status', headerName: 'Status', width: 170, editable: true },
];  

function QueueMgrTable() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
    const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);

    async function getData() {
        await axios
            .get('https://myendpoint.com/test/jobs', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
            })
            .then((response) =>{
                var test_data = response.data.data;
                setData(
                    test_data.map((x) => {
                        return {
                            id: parseInt(`${x.job_id}`),
                            file_name: `${x.file_name}`,
                            product_type: `${x.product_type}`,
                            status: `${x.status}`
                        }
                    })
                );
                setLoadingData(false);
            });
    }  
     
    useEffect((data) => {
        console.log(config);
        getData();
        if (loadingData) {
            getData();
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div style={{ height: 600, width: '100%' }}>
            {loadingData ? (
                <p>Loading. Please wait...</p>
        ) : (    
            <DataGrid
            columns={columns}
            pageSize={20}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
            checkboxSelection
            components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
            onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
                const selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
                const selectedRows = data.rows.filter((row) =>
                    selectedIDs.has(row.id),
            );
            setSelectedRows(selectedRows);
            }}
            rows={data}
            />
        )}
    
        <pre style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>
            {JSON.stringify(selectedRows, null, 4)}
        </pre>
        </div>
    );
};

export default QueueMgrTable;
```

When I click on a row in the above, I get the following error. Any suggestions or clues as to what I am doing wrong here? I suspect that it trying to use filter when the `data` is undefined for some reason due to state.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I had to make a few simple changes to the following block of code. First, I changed `const` to `let`. Then I had to remove the `rows` from `data.rows.filter((row) ...` as it was undefined. The data object is already defined as an array, and therefore, I can use the filter method to find the correct "row" data based on the `id`.

```
onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
    let selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
    let selectedRows = data.filter((row) =>
        selectedIDs.has(row.id),
    );
    setSelectedRows(selectedRows);
}}
```

This resolved the error issue and allowed me to properly define `selectedIDs`.

Comment: You shouldn't have to change `const` to `let` , did you try to change that back after fixing the `data.rows.filter((row) ...`  array?  That looks to be the only issue.